# How to make buttons on Java Swing Application when constantly redrawing frames

Tags: java, swing

**The simple version** is that I'm drawing Graphics2D 60 times a second on a JPanel and it uses the drawstring method to create a bunch of labels. How would I go about making so I can click on those labels and have something happen?

**Explanation:** As it currently stands I have a system setup that says for every object in the world draw a string to the side (So I can see a list of all objects in the world). This is done with a for loop and the Graphics2D drawstring method.

The JPanel is being updated 60 times a second so this is being redrawn 60 times a second. I want to be able to click on these object labels so I can select the items, how would I go about turning them into buttons?

I messed around with JButton for awhile but it didn't seem to do me any good because whenever I added it the JPanel would go blank and only the button would render (Plus it didn't render to the right size).

**More Details:**

I use a

```
for(int I=0; I < sceneObjects.size(); I++) {

}
```

loop to grab every object in an object ArrayList. Each object has a String variable "Name". Before the loop class I sent an int called YPosition, and for every object the YPosition goes up by 20 so that the labels don't all stack on top of each other. I'm using the g2d.DrawString method to achieve this. But I need to be able to select the object labels.

I apologize if I forgot something in my question, let me know.

For those who are curious, the code looks exactly like this (Can't be compiled as is):

```
    g2d.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, hierarchyWidth / 26));
    g2d.setColor(Color.black);
    int oYPos = 20;
    // For every object in existence
    for(int i=0; i < engine.sceneObjects.activeObjects.size(); i++) {
        GameObject theObject = engine.sceneObjects.activeObjects.get(i);
        // If the scrollbar is within range of the hierarchy
        // (Based on HierarchyHeight so that it's resolution friendly)
        if(oYPos >= hierarchyScroll && oYPos < hierarchyScroll + hierarchyHeight) {
            // If the object has no parent
            if(theObject.transform.parent == null) {
                g2d.drawString(theObject.name, hierarchyPosition.x + 5, hierarchyPosition.y + oYPos);
            } else { // If the object has a parent

            }
        }
        oYPos += 20;
    }
    // Track the last oYPos so that the scrollbar can adjust itself accordingly
    lastOYPos = oYPos;
```

**My guess** would be some sort of class create for each of these labels and a Boolean stored called isSelected, and then rendering the label according to the class, but this seems a bit more complicated than I'd like to do

Comment: `How would I go about making so I can click on those labels and have something happen?` - why don't you actually use a JLabel for the text instead of drawing it yourself. Then you can add a MouseListener to the label. Or you could even use a JButton, (but don't paint the Border) and you can add an ActionLIstener to the button.

Comment: I was under the impression that JLabels (Like JButtons) are dangerous have to be added to the JPanel every frame which would mean I'd have to create an add a ton of JLabel's to the JPanel 60 times a second which seems really expensive in terms of optimization. I was also under the impression that JLabels have to be added through layout and you can't just set their position

Comment: @kriller509 You'd only have to create the labels when you need them, so unless you're changing all the entities you're displaying every frame, you shouldn't have a problem. You'd need to devise your own positioning code though. Another solution would be to store a `Rectangle` of each label (associated with each entity) and use a `MouseListener` to determine which label was clicked on. Again, you'd only need to create this `Rectangle` once per entity adding and removing it as you add and remove entities

Comment: `I was also under the impression that JLabels have to be added through layout and you can't just set their position` - why do you think you can't use a layout manager for this? You are just stacking the text vertically. This is easily done with a layout manager.

Comment: @camickr For layout I've just been doing a large cache of at-the-start calculations based on screen resolution to determine position and size of different things because after reading 3 guides and the API I couldn't figure out how to go about using a LayoutManager

Comment: @MadProgrammer Because these are drawn in Graphics2D which is repainted it would get cleared if I didn't redraw them every frame

Comment: `after reading 3 guides and the API I couldn't figure out how to go about using a LayoutManager ` - I have no idea what your confusion might be. You simply set the layout manager of the panel,  create the component and add the component to the panel  This is easily done by using a vertical `BoxLayout` or maybe even a `GridLayout` (I don't know your exact requirement). Read the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for working examples.

Comment: `it would get cleared if I didn't redraw them every frame` - if you use components. You just change the text of the component and it will automatically repaint itself.

Comment: @camickr But the JPanel I use to draw these also draws moving objects on another part of the screen so it needs to constantly be repainting which would make the exercise of repainting when text changes pointless

Comment: It sounds to me like the text is static and you have moving objects. So, the text should be in a separate panel so it doesn't have to be repainted all the time. The moving objects should be in their own panel.

Comment: @kriller509 *"Because these are drawn in Graphics2D which is repainted it would get cleared if I didn't redraw them every frame"* - I don't see your point, since Swing components are painted independently, they wouldn't be affected by what you're doing, unless you're using a `BufferStrategy`, but since you've provided zero context, it's impossible to suggest any one solution over another